# How to order by 'something' in React Native FlatList?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here is my entire code at Home.js file

```
export default function Home({navigation}) {

const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([
    { title: 'Alfa Romeo 147 1.9JTD', rating: 2020, body: 340000, sg: ['ABS ',  'CD ', 'ESP '], key: '1' },
    { title: 'Gotta Catch Them All (again)', body: 'lorem ipsum', key: '2' },
    { title: 'Not So "Final" Fantasy', body:'lorem ipsum', key: '3' },
    { title: 'Alfaromeo', rating: 3200, body: 'blablabla', first:'loremlo', key: '4' },
    { title: 'Gotta Catch Them All (again)', rating: 4, body: 'lorem ipsum', key: '5' },
    { title: 'Not So "Final" Fantasy', rating: 3, body: 'lorem ipsum', key: '6' },
    { title: 'Alfaromeo', rating: 3200, body: 'sadaa', key: '7' },
    { title: 'Gotta Catch Them All (again)', rating: 4, body: 'lorem ipsum', key: '8' },
    
  ]);

 return (
<View style={styles.container}>
<FlatList data={reviews} renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ReviewDetails', item)}>
        
        <View style={styles.content}>
            <Image
            style={styles.image}
            source={{
            uri: 'https://www.autoplac-cg.me/storage/1871/conversions/5f9eb91821de1_20FB3486-4A0A-4B4A-B13C-CAE912950E22-thumb.jpg',
            }}
            />
            <Text style={styles.headertext}>{item.title }</Text>
            <Text style={styles.infotext}>{item.rating}god. | {item.body}km <Text style={styles.collapse}>+</Text></Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )} />
</View>
```

);
}

So I want to put first on FlatList that review who has in array 'first', so in code its fourth. How I can do that?

I want to this be first on FlatList

**{ title: 'Alfaromeo', rating: 3200, body: 'blablabla', first:'loremlo', key: '4' }**

Comment: Care to explain a Lil bit more in detail? Explained and detailed questions are more likely to be resolved faster.

Comment: It's just a regular FlatList, and I want a custom order in FlatList not just order by default    @HimanshuBansal

Comment: Sorry, No other solution I could find. Victor Kayan's answer is good and you should go with that. ^^

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the best way to do that is to sort the data as needed and then render it with FlatList.

The sort logic may be the way you need, which means that you are free to "order by 'anything'" if you wish.

According to the data set and information you provided, the business rule, as I understood, is to show the items with `fisrt` flag at first place. So, the sorting could be like this:

```js
export default function Home({navigation}) {
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([
    { title: 'Alfa Romeo 147 1.9JTD', rating: 2020, body: 340000, sg: ['ABS ',  'CD ', 'ESP '], key: '1' },
    { title: 'Gotta Catch Them All (again)', body: 'lorem ipsum', key: '2' },
    { title: 'Not So "Final" Fantasy', body:'lorem ipsum', key: '3' },
    { title: 'Alfaromeo', rating: 3200, body: 'blablabla', first:'loremlo', key: '4' },
    { title: 'Gotta Catch Them All (again)', rating: 4, body: 'lorem ipsum', key: '5' },
    { title: 'Not So "Final" Fantasy', rating: 3, body: 'lorem ipsum', key: '6' },
    { title: 'Alfaromeo', rating: 3200, body: 'sadaa', key: '7' },
    { title: 'Gotta Catch Them All (again)', rating: 4, body: 'lorem ipsum', key: '8' },
  ]);

  function renderItem(item) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ReviewDetails', item)}>
          <View style={styles.content}>
              <Image
                style={styles.image}
                source={{
                uri: 'https://www.autoplac-cg.me/storage/1871/conversions/5f9eb91821de1_20FB3486-4A0A-4B4A-B13C-CAE912950E22-thumb.jpg',
                }}
              />
              <Text style={styles.headertext}>{item.title}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.infotext}>{item.rating}god. | {item.body}km <Text style={styles.collapse}>+</Text></Text>
          </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

  function sortData() {
    let sortedArray = [];

    // If the item contains "first" property, it will be placed at the beginning of the sortedArray, else it will be at the end of it
    reviews.forEach(review => (
      review.first
        ? sortedArray = [review, ...sortedArray]
        : sortedArray.push(review)
    ));

    return sortedArray;
  }

 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
      data={sortData()}
      renderItem={({ item }) => renderItem(item)}
    />
  </View>
 );
}
```

*I moved the code to render an item to a separated function just for convenience*

Comment: That is great! I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Use array.sort with providing compare function

See: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp

You can use

```
reviews.sort((a, b) => a.rating - b.rating)
```

This will sort your reviews array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do is

```
var reviews1 = reviews.filter(function (el) {
  return el["first"];
});

var reviews2 = reviews.filter(function (el) {
  return el["first"] === undefined;
});

const reviewsFinalArray = reviews1.concat(reviews2); // Your result
```